# Newtsonsoft - fInd a property buried in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

While parsing a JSON string, I want to test whether a property exists so the app won't throw a "null reference" error in the case the JSON property didn't make it into the string.

The property I'm looking for is buried in the JSON

```
dateofbirth = (string) o["Person"]["Demographics"]["Birthdate"]["Date"];
```

And when I try to access the property

```
var JSONBirthDate = o.Property("Birthdate");
```

It always returns "null" - I've searched around and can't find the syntax for grabbing a property down in the JSON hierarchy.

Once I can do this, I'm guessing I just check it like this:

```
if(property != null) {
    // do something
}
```

And provide a default value.

Comment: Sounds like [JSONPath may be what you're looking for](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) for this purpose:

```
var dateofbirth = (string)o.SelectToken("Person.Demographics.Birthdate.Date");
```

It supports array indexing as well as property selection.  E.g., if you had an array of people instead of a single person, you could do:

```
var dateofbirth = (string)o.SelectToken("People[0].Demographics.Birthdate.Date");
```

It also supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) including the wildcard and recursive descent operator.  For the full syntax, see [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).